I can't use MQTT.js node package with CDN
I installed mosquitto at the following path:
C:\Program Files\mosquitto

Then I launched it with the following command:
mosquitto.exe

Then I wrote the following code on the "test.html" file.
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const client = mqtt.connect('ws://localhost');
    const topic = `mytopic`;
    client.on('connect', function () {
      console.log('Connected to broker MQTT');
      client.subscribe(topic, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(`Subscription success`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Subscription failure: ${err}`);
        }
      });
    });
    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        console.log(topic, message.toString());
    });
</script>

This is the error I get
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/' failed

P.S.
In my "mosquitto.conf" file I have added the following lines:
listener 8080
protocol websockets

All the other lines are commented. Then I replaced
const client = mqtt.connect('ws://localhost');

with
const client = mqtt.connect('ws://localhost:8080');

But it still doesn't work.

In their page they say " The only protocol supported in browsers is MQTT over WebSockets, so you must use ws:// or wss:// protocols". Using only "localhost" hasn't worked.

[!IMPORTANT] The only protocol supported in browsers is MQTT over WebSockets, so you must use ws:// or wss:// protocols.     As such do you have protocol websockets  in your mosquitto config?

no, what should i write on my my mosquitto.conf?

Could you edit your question and add your mosquitto.conf settings.

Do the mosquitto logs say -> Open websockets listen socket on port 8080  ?    Also I would set anonymous: true if you are not sending credentials.

the mosquitto log says nothing

Well that doesn't seem right, are you calling mosquitto.exe from a command prompt, or as a service?.   If you use a command prompt you can do mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf to see what's happening.

Mosquitto does not load any configuration file by default when started on the command line (the mosquitto service on windows will load a mosquitto.conf file from the default install directory).
E.g. running mosquitto will not load any configuration file and will only listen on localhost and on port 1883. It also will not allow any anonymous users to connect.
To use a configuration file you must pass it on the command line with the -c option.
e.g. mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf (assuming the mosquitto.conf is in the same directory you run the command).
To run a broker with websocket support and to allow anonymous users to connect you must have the following in the config file
# allow anonymous users
allow_anonymous true

# start the default listener
listener 1883

# start the websocket listener
listener 8080
protocol websockets

